# Как в C++ вымерять время работы ОДНОЙ операции c числами?

Tags: c++

Задание звучит так: сравнить быстродействие арифметических операций с числами разных типов. Для этого нужно измерить скорость выполнения одной операции, например, **сложение**, между двумя числами одного типа, например, **int**. Так как вымерять время ровно одной операции будет затруднительно, да и результат выйдет очень неточным, то я решил сделать цикл с большим количеством умножений, и общее время поделить на количество операций, таким образом уменьшив погрешность измерений. Но проблема в том, что современные компиляторы очень сильно оптимизируют код автоматически, поэтому простой код наподобии такого:

```cpp
// засекает время, которое тратиться на 
// выполнение цикла и просвоений
double delta() { 
    int a;
    // засекаем начало
    for(int i=0;i<ITERATIONS_NUM;i++) {
        a = i;
        a %= MOD;
    }
    // вычисляем время
    return t;
}

double measure() { 
    int a;
    // засекаем начало
    for(int i=0;i<ITERATIONS_NUM;i++) {
        a += i;
        a %= MOD;
    }
    // вычисляем время
    return t;
}

double time = measure() - delta();
```

не выдает адекватные результаты. Есть ли какие-то способы получить наиболее приближённые к реальным результаты?

Comment: Использовать все значения.

Comment: @Qwertiy все значения чего?

Comment: Всё, что вычисляется, должно быть использовано. Нельзя просто перетирать переменную и надо в конце вывести результат.

Comment: @Qwertiy но я же и использую все переменные, которые ввожу, и `a` и `i`

Comment: Как используется a?

Comment: @MBo присвоение не в счёт? тоесть надо, чтобы и `a` и `i` присутствовали справа от присвоения?

Comment: Нет, ты их вообще не используешь. На каждой итерации переменная `a` затирается новым значением, значит все итерации кроме последней не нужны. Но после последней `a` не используется, значит она тоже не нужна. Выкидываем нафиг и цикл, и переменную и просто возвращаем какое-то t.

Comment: По окончании процедуры локальная переменная a никому не нужна, поэтому компилятор может решить, что вся работа насмарку, и удалить код цикла

Comment: Кажеться, я понял, в чем суть, попробую переписать. А `volatile` не вариант, если мне надо не абсолютную величину, а именно отношение скорости разных операций между разными типами?

Comment: Отключить оптимизацию. А если уж совсем не отключается, то сделать ассемблерную вставку из интересующих команд.

Comment: @pepsicoca1 имеете ввиду флаги компиляции?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/company/raiffeisenbank/blog/466719/

Comment: Отключить оптимизацию это да, выключить оптимизацию с помощью флагов компиляции.